# Repository Pattern Question

Tags: database, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC app and I'm using a repository to store and retrieve view objects. My question is, is it okay for the implementation of the various repositories to call each other? I.E. can the `ICustomerRepository` implementation call an implementation of `IAddressRepository`, or should it handle its own updates to the address data source?

EDIT:

Thanks everyone, the the Customer/Address example isn't real. The actual problem involves three aggregates which update a fourth aggregate in response to changes in their respective states. I in this case it seems a conflict between introducing dependencies vs violating the don't repeat yourself principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a repository for each aggregate root.

I have no knowledge of your domain-model, but it doesn't feel natural for me to have an IAddressRepository.   Unless 'Address' is an aggregate root in your domain.

In fact, in most circumstances, 'Address' is not even an entity, but a value object.  That is, in most cases the identity of an 'Address' is determined by its value (the value of all its properties); it does not have a separate 'Id' (key) field.
So, when this is the case, the CustomerRepository should be responsible for storing the Address, as the Address is a part of the Customer aggregate-root.

**Edit (ok so your situation was just an example):**

But, if you have other situations where you would need another repository in a repository, then I think that it is better to remove that functionality out of that repository, and put it in a separate class (Service).
I mean:  I think that, if you have some functionality inside a repository A, that relies on another repository B, then this kind of functionality doesn't belong inside repository A.
Instead, write another class (which is called a Service in DDD), in where you implement this functionality.

Anyway, I do not think that repositories should really call each other.  If you do not want to write a Service however, and if you really want to keep that logic inside the repository itself, then pass the other repository as an argument in that specific method.

I hope I made myself a bit clear. :P

Answer (score 2):

They really shouldn't call each other.  A Repository is an abstraction of the (more or less) atomic operations that you want to perform on your domain.  The less dependency they have, the better.  Realistically, any consumer of a repository should expect to be able to point the repository class at a database and have it perform the necessary domain operations without a lot of configuration.

They should also represent "aggregates" in your domain - i.e. key focal points that a lot of functionality will be based around.  I'm wondering why you would have a separate address information repository?  Shouldn't that be part of your customer repository?

Comment: That was just an example for simplicity's sake. The actual model is of a rather complex inventory system, there are multiple interfaces centered around several existing aggregates through which the user can modify the same inventory data, which in turn is also it's own aggregate for (limited) direct modification.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of repository (or at least the consequences do) but in general if you have data repositories calling each other you're going to run into problems with things like cyclical (repo A -> requires B -> requires C -. oops, requires A) or recursive data loads (A-> requires B & C -> C-requires D, E -> .... ->..ad nauseum). Testing also becomes more difficult.

For example, you need to load your address repository to properly run your customer repository, because the customer repository calls the address repo. If you need to test the customer repo, you'll need to do a db load of the addresses or mock them in some way, and ultimately you won't be able to load and test any single system repository without loading them all.

Having those dependencies is also kind of insidious because they're often not clear - usually you're dealing with a repository as a data-holding abstraction - if you have to be conscious of how they depend on each other you can't use them as an abstraction, but have to manage the load process whenever you want to use them.